# PostgreSQL: proper way to delete 'orphaned' records

Tags: postgresql

In my current project, a have a few cases where, within data pump operations, I have to execute queries like this (it's not a real example, but it should give you some idea):

```
DELETE FROM notification
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM user)
```

On big tables, such construction performs poorly, I believe it's because of `NOT IN` construction, which makes it impossible to use indexes.

Such approach should perform better:

```
DELETE FROM notification
USING (
    SELECT n.user_id, u.id FROM notification
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON n.user_id = u.id
) i
WHERE 
        notification.user_id = i.user_id 
    AND i.id IS NULL
```

... but it looks a bit overcomplicated.

Is there a better way / best practice for such operations?

Comment: You can use CTEs for that `WITH`-Clause. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `EXISTS` instead:

```
DELETE FROM notification
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT id FROM user WHERE id = notification.user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `NOT EXISTS`.

```
DELETE FROM notification n
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM "user" u
                                     WHERE u.id = n.user_id);
```

But what you really should do is adding a foreign key constraint so that such rows cannot exist in the first place. Assuming that `"user".id` already is a (primary) key:

```
ALTER TABLE notification
            ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
                            REFERENCES "user"
                                       (id);
```

If `"user".id` isn't a (primary) key, you first need to change that and make it a (primary) key.

Comment: I deliberately not use a FK contraint in these cases (data pump removes all records and then reloads them again from warehouse, if there will be a FK — I can end up with DB lock). But your point is valid for generic cases, thanks.